# where to download Virtual PC addins?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-virtual-pc, windows

I am using Virtual PC 2007 on Windows Vista Enterprise x86. I need Virtual PC addins to enable functions like shared folder between host and guest OS.

But I am very surprised I can not find a download URL from search. Could anyone point me to the download URL for my platform please?

thanks in advance,
George

EDIT1:

After install the additionals, I still can not set the Folder Sharing option, here is my screen snapshot, any ideas what is wrong? i39.tinypic.com/91h10w.jpg

Answer (score 4):

In 2007 if my memory serves correctly when you open a virtual machine up, go into the file menu and its something like "Install virtual additionals" and it will guide you though the installer.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed the Additions, but where to set the shared folder? From the Virtual PC settings, I still find the option of shared folder is greyed out. Should I set shared folder option inside guest OS?

Comment: When the machine is closed, in the main VPC right click on the machine and select settings and then about fourth from the bottom is "Folder Sharing"

Comment: After install the additionals, I still can not set the Folder Sharing option, here is my screen snapshot, any ideas what is wrong?

http://i39.tinypic.com/91h10w.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Virtual Machine Additions generally isn't a download, it's a feature of the Virtual PC software that just needs 'switching on'.

[This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824561) shows how to do it in Virtual PC 2004, I suspect the procedure would be similar in Virtual PC 2007.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed the Additions, but where to set the shared folder? From the Virtual PC settings, I still find the option of shared folder is greyed out. Should I set shared folder option inside guest OS?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Virtual Additions installed, start up the VPC and log on.  Then from the settings menu (either the "Settings" button on the Virtual PC Console, or "Settings" under the Edit Menu on the actual VPC window) down towards the bottom should be the "Shared Folders" options.  Note that from experience I have found that it depends upon which version of OS your VPC is running as to whether you can add Shared Folders or not.  XP definitely supports them.  Click on the "Share Folder..." button, and select a folder to share.  You can only share local folders, network drives are not allowed.  Also remember to set the "Share every time" checkbox if you want the folder shared each time you start up the VPC.